# Referring to Python console variable in function

Tags: python, variables, console, scope

I'm not sure about the scope rules of Python. If I'm using the Python console and define a variable, then import a module and call a function in that module, is there a way to refer to the variable within the function? For instance:

```
>> option = 2
>> import choosingModule
>> choosingModule.choosingFunction()
```

And then in choosingModule:

```
def choosingFunction():
    if option == 0:
        doThis()
    elif option == 1:
        doThat()
    elif option == 2:
        doTheOtherOne()
    else:
        doWhateverYouFeelLike()
```

Obviously that is a simple example. The reason why I want to do this is that I have four different versions of a function and I want to be able to choose from the console which one should be used. The function is called fairly deep in to the code, so I don't want to have to pass a parameter through every single function call, especially as I only need to compare them at the testing stage; when this reaches the production version, only one of will be used.

So, is there any way to refer to a Python console variable in a called function? Or is there perhaps some other way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the REPL, you're the `__main__` module, so you can import that and use the variables from it:

```
def choosingFunction():
    option = __import__('__main__').option
    if option == 0:
        doThis()
    elif option == 1:
        doThat()
    elif option == 2:
        doTheOtherOne()
    else:
        doWhateverYouFeelLike()
```

However, a better way to do this if you don't absolutely *need* the variable to be defined in the console is to set it on `choosingModule`. Then:

```
def choosingFunction():
    global option
    if option == 0:
        doThis()
    elif option == 1:
        doThat()
    elif option == 2:
        doTheOtherOne()
    else:
        doWhateverYouFeelLike()
```

```
>>> import choosingModule
>>> choosingModule.option = 2
>>> choosingModule.choosingFunction()
```

However, you should only use either while testing. **Please don't use these in production code.**

Comment: Your first solution gives me the error message "AttributeError: 'FakeModule' object has no attribute 'option'".

Comment: @thornate: That looks like an IPython thing. Unfortunately, I can't replicate that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to keep that variable in the global scope and access it using the *global* statement.

The keyword *global* allows you to reference a variable in the global namespace despite the existence of another variable with the same name on the function caller.

For example: this will print "tangerine"

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        return fruit
    fruit = "tangerine"
    return bar2()

fruit = "banana"
print(foo()) # will print "tangerine"
```

But this will print "banana".

```
def foo2():
    def bar2():
        global fruit # fetch me the fruit in the global scope
        return fruit
    fruit = "tangerine"
    return bar2()

fruit = "banana"
print(foo2()) # will print "banana"
```

without the global keyword, the interpreter will follow the "LEGB rule" in order to find the variable you're trying to reference:

1. **L** ocal Scope: first, it'll search for the variable in the local scope, the scope in which your function statements are being executed. Local scopes are created everytime a function is called.
2. **E** nclosing Scopes: secondly, the interpreter will look for the variable in the "enclosing function locals", that is the functions in which your function is inserted (declared). That's where the *fruit* variable is found on the *return fruit* statement inside *bar()*.
3. **G** lobal: if the variable was not found on the namespaces above, python will try to find it among the global variables. The usage of the *global* statement forces python to look for it only on the global scope, thus skipping 1 and 2.
4. **B** uiltins: at last, python will try to find the variable among the built-in functions and constants. No magic here.

If all of the searches above fail to find the variable name, python will raise a *NameError* Exception:

```
$ NameError: name 'fruit' is not defined
```

Then you could do:

```
def choosingFunction():
    global option
    if option == 0:
        doThis()
    elif option == 1:
        doThat()
    elif option == 2:
        doTheOtherOne()
    else:
        doWhateverYouFeelLike()

>> option = 2
>> import choosingModule
>> choosingModule.choosingFunction()
```

Keep in mind that relying on the existence of a global variable in the module that is calling yours is considered a very bad practice, and mustn't be used in anything serious. ;)

For more information on the *global* statement, check the documentation: [Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) and [Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement). 
And for info about the scopes and namespaces rules check [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) (Python 3.x) or [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html) (Python 2.7).